# BadParcelableException when pressing "Recent Apps" button in DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, badparcelableexception

I am trying to make a DialogFragment which can be reused in different Fragments without creating a new one using the following code.

All this code that I am going to put below works correctly, the buttons work, the texts are also seen, the problem is when I press the Recent Applications button of the mobile, the app crashes with the following error:

`android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object(name = com.mypackage.models.MyDialogInfo)`

I am creating a DialogFragment called MyCustomDialogFragment which receives MyDialogInfo model as an argument.

```
class MyDialogInfo(
    val id:String,
    val title:String,
    val body:String, 
    val firstButton: ButtonInfo?=null, 
    val secondaryButton: ButtonInfo?= null
):Serializable
```

```
class ButtonInfo(
    val text:String?=null,
    val textCharSequence:CharSequence?=null,
    val callback: CallbackButton
):Serializable{
    
    interface CallbackButton{
        fun onAction()
    }
}
```

In MyCustomDialogFragment I'm receiving arguments and using them like this:

```
private val args: MyCustomDialogFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onViewCreated(view:View, savedInstanceState:Bundle?){
    super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState)
    setUpPrimaryButton(args.dialoginfo.firstButton)
    setUpSecondaryButton(args.dialoginfo.secondaryButton)
}

private fun setUpPrimaryButton(button: ButtonInfo?){
    
    with(binding){
        if(button == null){
            btPrimary.hide()
        }else {
            btPrimary.show()
            btPrimary.text= button.text
            btPrimary.setOnClickListener{
                dismiss()
                args.dialoginfo.firstButton?.callback?.onAction()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun setUpSecondaryButton(button: ButtonInfo?){
    
    with(binding){
        if(button == null){
            btSec.hide()
        }else {
            btSec.show()
            
            if(!button.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
                btSec.text = button.text
            }else if(!button.textChar.isNullOrEmpty()){
                 btSec.text = button.textChar
            }
      
            btSec.setOnClickListener{
                dismiss()
                args.dialoginfo.secondaryButton?.callback?.onAction()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in other Fragments, I use this DialogFragment in this way:

```
private var customDialogInfo :MyDialogInfo?=null

override fun onViewCreated(view:View, savedInstanceState:Bundle?){
    super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState)
    setUpButton()
}

private setUpButton(){
    btnDoSomething.setOnClickListener{
        goToCustomDialog(
            title = "Title",
            body = "Body",
            fistButton = ButtonInfo(
                text = "Text Button",
                callback = object: CallbackButton{
                    override fun onAction(){
                        //Do Something
                    }
                }
            ),
             secondaryButton = ButtonInfo(
                text = "Text Button 2",
                callback = object: CallbackButton{
                    override fun onAction(){
                        //Do Something
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    }
}


private fun goToCustomDialog(
    title:String,
    body:String, 
    firstButton: ButtonInfo?=null, 
    secondaryButton: ButtonInfo?= null
){
    customDialogInfo = MyDialogInfo(
        id= UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        title = title,
        body = body,
        firstButton = firstButton,
        secondaryButton = secondaryButton
    )
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.custom_dialog_fragment, bundleOf(Pair("dialoginfo",customDialogInfo)))
}
```